# Backbone click event not firing

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

So I have a Backbone view in which I declare it's className. I'm trying to bind a click event to that class. So something like this:

```
className: "question"
events:
    "click .question": -> console.log("clicked")
```

This doesn't seem to work. It seems to be because the element isn't inside the view itself. So if I create an element within a template, I can bind to that just fine. I should be able to bind to the view itself right? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> [...] Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. The `callback` may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct function body. Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

So you want your `events` to look like this:

```
events:
    'click': -> console.log('clicked')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6W6QE/

Comment: Heh. Whoops. Must have missed that part. Thank you!